# Directory rewrite URL in Apache, htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I urgently need help in rewriting php URLs for my site. I have researched and tried everything but it's still not working.

I want to rewrite all the URLs in my htaccess file to rename the directory '_public' to 'art':

```
www.site.com/_public/work.php
```

so all url's show:

```
www.site.com/art/work.php
```

Can anyone help? would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to go to 'www.site.com/art/work.php' and get the page located at 'www.site.com/_public/work.php' displayed.

In .htaccess (in the root directory) do:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^art/(.+)$ /_public/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Thanks but  I can't get it working still, maybe I'm placing in the wrong place. I've tried placing it in the htaccess file in the _public directory and in the directory above that

Answer (score 1):

Please add below lines in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^art/(.+)$ /_public/$1
```

Comment: Thanks but  I can't get it working still, maybe I'm placing in the wrong place. I've tried placing it in the htaccess file in the _public directory and in the directory above that